# How to use a TEdit box to enter password without showing the characters that is bing entered and only showing a *

Tags: delphi, passwords, delphi-xe2, edit

I want to make an edit box where an user must enter a password. When they enter the password I want the character not to be displayed, and rather an *. Are there any properties that can be set to do this, I know how to set the TEdit to remain blank while entering but I do not want that. Im using Delphi  XE2

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I remember from my old days in Delphi that TEdit had a property for that.

Searching on Google, I found [this](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TCustomEdit.PasswordChar)

Namely: "Use the PasswordChar property to create an edit control that displays a special character in place of any entered text."

Answer (score 6):

I have seen that in the TEdit there is a property named PasswordChar. I assigned the * value to it and now the Edit box does not show the characters that is entered into the box